# SQL to JPQL left join with is null

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have two entities: Profile & ProfileClubMapping. The ProfileClubMapping consists of Profile_ID, Club_ID and Status. It is used as a join table. 
I want now to select all Profiles and if existing a ProfileClubMapping with a specific Club_ID. I successfully wrote an SQL :

```
SELECT p.LASTNAME, pcm.STATUS FROM PROFILE p 
LEFT JOIN PROFILECLUBMAPPING pcm ON pcm.PROFILE_ID = p.ID AND pcm.CLUB_ID = 480
```

But i have trouble to convert it to jpql. I tried something like that:

```
SELECT p.username,pcm FROM Profile p 
LEFT JOIN ProfileClubMapping pcm ON pcm.profile = p 
WHERE pcm.club.id = 480 OR pcm is null
```

The only thing that is missing are the profiles which don´t have any ProfileClubMapping at all. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Left join with where condition is inner join, you need to move the where clause to on clause.

Comment: you are totally right! solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your `Profile` entity contains a collection of `ProfileClubMapping` entities called `mappings`, then the JPQL to do this would be:

```
SELECT p.username, pcm.status
FROM Profile p LEFT JOIN p.mappings pcm
WHERE pcm.club.id = 480
```

If not, perhaps you could post the code of your Entity classes to help us create a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Left join with where condition is inner join, you need to move the where clause to on clause.